# Rename Standard new related list button

Tags: related-list, button, new, standard

Is it possible to rename standard related list button without replacing  standard new button with a new custom url hack button  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot rename the standard buttons. You'll have to create a new button then uncheck the new button from the related list buttons.

To create the url hack a tutorial I found is here: http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

By using a relative link you can remove the first part of the link https://na1.salesforce.com and jsut start with / so it will be dynamic to whatever environment you are in. Also, comes in handy if your org gets mirgrated to a different pod.

Please vote for this idea to rename standard buttons

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpSvAAK

Comment: Since we need to update parent lookup field on child record ...need to use url hack button right ?

Comment: Yes. should be fairly straightforward populating the field. Note lookups need the field=record&fild_lkid=recordid

Comment: if we push button to new environment  then we need to update url hack button since field ID changes right ?

Comment: if it's already in prod the id would not change. If it's not in Prod but in the sandbox it probably will change.